# Scroll when navigating keys using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm using the following jquery script to navigate a list with keys:
http://firedev.com/jquery.keynav/

Since the list is sometimes long, it goes a long way down. If I navigate down, then it goes off screen.

What would be a good solution so that the browser scrolls down once it goes off screen or perhaps some other solution? I would appreciate if someone could help me with examples. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Have you already tried something? Can you add some code to your question?

Comment: I haven't sir. Right now, I lack the neccessary skill to be able to think of a solution for this case, that's why I registered here hoping to get some help. The code is the same as the source code in that link.

Comment: you can do two distinct things: change the style to ensure than all your tabs can be visualized on screen without scroll or change the script to see the offset of your tab and if is greater than your screen scroll down programmatically

Comment: @kamus Thank you for your input. Could you please provide code examples of what it could look like with the second alternative? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the jquery.keynav find the `setCurrent` function

```
function setCurrent(i,j) {
            if (i<0) i=(matrix.length-1);
            if (i>=matrix.length) i=0;
            if (j<0) j=(matrix[i].length-1);
            if (j>=matrix[i].length) j=0;
            current.removeClass('selected');
            current = $(matrix[i][j]);
            current.addClass('selected');
            x=i;
            y=j;
if(!checkVisible(current))
                $('html, body').animate({
                       scrollTop: current.offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }


function checkVisible( elm, eval ) {
    eval = eval || "visible";
    var vpH = $(window).height(), // Viewport Height
        st = $(window).scrollTop(), // Scroll Top
        y = $(elm).offset().top,
        elementHeight = $(elm).height();

    if (eval == "visible") return ((y < (vpH + st)) && (y > (st - elementHeight)));
    if (eval == "above") return ((y < (vpH + st)));
}
```

it will scroll to the element

Comment: Thanks for the example Kamus. This example works but it's scrolling up and down on every up/down keystroke. Do you know know how I can make it so that it scrolls up and down if the next list item is not visible?

Comment: Amazing work @Kamus. Tried it out real quick and it seems to work great!